# Question on association measures for binary data

Tags: correlation, spss, binary-data, association-measure

I need help to understand the article [Measures for Binary Data](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_20.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_proximities_measures_binary_data.htm) from the SPSS knowledge center. Especially I do not understand how to interpret the parameters $p$ and $np$. All the defining equations of the documented measures have the form

$$F(x,y) := f(a,b,c,d)$$

which doesn't make sense to me mathematically. What does $(x,y)$ on the left side mean and how is it related to the right side?

I don't get a clear picture of this by introductory remarks:

[image]

Comment: It is very simple. X and Y are two binary data vectors of equal length. The vectors could be rows of the dataset (i.e. cases, respondents) or columns therein (i.e. variables, attributes). Association measure F(X,Y) is the (dis)similarity function computed between the vectors. P and NP are syntax parameters you feed to the program: P is the "positive" value and NP is the "nonpositive" value in your data. Typically P is 1 and NP is 0 as we code binary data. For more, please read Command Syntax Reference doc, `PROXIMITIES` command.

Comment: @ttnphns seems like you could make this an answer and claim the reputation ;)

Comment: @IWS, I won't because the question is more about SPSS docs than about statistics, although it is somewhat statistical too.

Comment: @ttnphns True, but then I guess this question will remain unanswered or it should be flagged as inappropriate for CV.

Comment: @ttnphns: I see, the variables $(x,y)$ do not refer to $p$ and $np$ but to two vectors $x,y$ (which seems to be taken for granted). $p$ and $np$ then are used to calculate the 2x2 contingency table with its entries $a,b,c,d$. Thus we have $a = a(x,y,p,np)$ and so on with optional arguments $p, np$.

Comment: Yes. Let n be the length of the vectors, i.e. the number of the pairs of their elements; then $a$ is the count of pairs where X=P AND Y=P; $b$ is likewise the count where X=P AND Y=NP, etc etc.